# pandas: groupby 2 columns, keeping all rows with unique values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

i have a pandas dataframe which looks like this

```
from pandas import datetime as date
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 
                  'date':[date(2020, 5, 1), date(2020, 6, 1), date(2020, 7, 1), 
                          date(2020, 5, 1), date(2020, 6, 1), date(2020, 7, 1), 
                          date(2020, 5, 1), date(2020, 6, 1), date(2020, 7, 1)], 
                  'c':['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'abc', 
                       'abc', 'def', 'def']})

   a        date    c
0  A  2020-05-01  abc
1  A  2020-06-01  abc
2  A  2020-07-01  abc
3  B  2020-05-01  def
4  B  2020-06-01  xyz
5  B  2020-07-01  abc
6  C  2020-05-01  abc
7  C  2020-06-01  def
8  C  2020-07-01  def
```

i would like to group by column 'a' and 'c', count remaining rows by group of column 'a' and show all columns in my result.

output should look like this

```
   a        date    c    d
0  A  2020-05-01  abc    1
1  B  2020-05-01  def    3
2  B  2020-06-01  xyz    3
3  B  2020-07-01  abc    3
4  C  2020-05-01  abc    2
5  C  2020-06-01  def    2
```

Comment: It is not clear what the column `d` is supposed to represent. Could you please expand your answer to explain this in detail?

Comment: 'd' should be the count of values in column 'a' in the new df. so 'A' has a count of 1 in 'a', 'B' has a count of 3 in 'a' and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), then [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) and transform with the `size` of each group:

```
out = df.drop_duplicates(['a','c']).copy()
out['d'] = out.groupby(['a']).c.transform('size')
```

---

```
print(out)

   a       date    c  d
0  A 2020-05-01  abc  1
3  B 2020-05-01  def  3
4  B 2020-06-01  xyz  3
5  B 2020-07-01  abc  3
6  C 2020-05-01  abc  2
7  C 2020-06-01  def  2
```